# Microsoft Intune mdm cant remove outlook profile data in desktops and mac

Tags: microsoft-office-365, windows-10, mac, mdm, microsoft-intune

We have configured MDM and assigned E3 license and intune license. We have azure AD and intune MDM and also outlook with exchange. It seems that microsoft intune in Desktops cant remove outlook profile data even when we use retire option in intune.

**Please note:**
outlook data remove only works in mobiles such as android and ios.

We have properly signed up for the intune using   settings---access work or school--- enroll only in device management. (also we have assigned the proper license for Microsoft intune)

[image]

When we use retire option, in intune, in the pc itselt it gives below message but not removing outlook profile that has been cached .

"your company **has removed your workplace account and deleted all of the information associated with your workplace account (including business apps, password requirements, and other policies) from your device**"

[image]

Anyone succeeded in doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the current default behavior. **"intune will not remove office 365 outlook email"** "Intune cannot wipe the Outlook profile off of the Windows and Mac devices since they are saved locally and not in the application" 
That was the official answer from microsoft support agent

You can raise your voice to implement this feature in intune. 
Use below link to Vote up and comment , so that intune team will review it and decide.

https://microsoftintune.uservoice.com/forums/291681-ideas/suggestions/36305404-enable-intune-to-delete-outlook-profile-from-windo

Comment: How pathetic ms solutions!

Comment: Literally InTune should support deletion of outlook data in pcs, yet unfortunately it does not support this